# How to call facet_wrap() inside custom ggplot function?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I'm trying to create a function to combine the output from the package `rmcorr` with `ggplot`. The documentation for `rmcorr` includes an example on how to render the output with `ggplot`. I'm having trouble getting the grouping variable working for my custom function (3rd code paragraph below).

Here is the code and the following graph, without grouping variable for facetting, and where everything looks fine:

```
rmcorr_fun_2 <- function(p,m1,m2) {
  my.rmc <- rmcorr(participant = p, measure1 = m1, measure2 = m2, dataset = mtcars)
  print(my.rmc)
  p <- sym(p)
  m1 <- sym(m1)
  m2 <- sym(m2)
  #grp <- sym(grp)
  print(ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = !!m1, y = !!m2, group = factor(!!p), color = factor(!!p)))+
          geom_point(aes(colour = factor(!!p))) +
          geom_line(aes(y = my.rmc$model$fitted.values), linetype = 1))
          #facet_wrap(.~(!!grp)))
}
```

[image]

Using same codes above but adding grp variable and removing the hashes for grouping:

```
rmcorr_fun_2 <- function(p,m1,m2,grp) {
  my.rmc <- rmcorr(participant = p, measure1 = m1, measure2 = m2, dataset = mtcars)
  print(my.rmc)
  p <- sym(p)
  m1 <- sym(m1)
  m2 <- sym(m2)
  grp <- sym(grp)
  print(ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = !!m1, y = !!m2, group = factor(!!p), color = factor(!!p)))+
          geom_point(aes(colour = factor(!!p))) +
          geom_line(aes(y = my.rmc$model$fitted.values), linetype = 1)+
          facet_wrap(.~(!!grp)))
}
```

Gives the following error:

```
Error in sym(grp) : argument "grp" is missing, with no default
In addition: Warning message:
In rmcorr(participant = p, measure1 = m1, measure2 = m2, dataset = mtcars) :
  'p' coerced into a factor
Called from: is_symbol(x)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of formula notation you have to wrap the faceting variable inside `vars()`.

Also, instead of `sym + !!` you could simply make use of the `.data` pronoun from `rlang` in case you pass your column names as strings.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(rmcorr)

rmcorr_fun_2 <- function(p, m1, m2, grp) {
  my.rmc <- rmcorr(participant = p, measure1 = m1, measure2 = m2, dataset = mtcars)
  print(my.rmc)
  ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = .data[[m1]], y = .data[[m2]], group = factor(.data[[p]]), color = factor(.data[[p]]))) +
    geom_point(aes(colour = factor(.data[[p]]))) +
    geom_line(aes(y = my.rmc$model$fitted.values), linetype = 1) +
    facet_wrap(vars(.data[[grp]]))
}

rmcorr_fun_2("cyl", "hp", "disp", "cyl")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I intend to use with my own datasets so I need to able to set each variable. I actually just cut & pasted the sym & !! from another post but I don't quite understand what it does. I just adapted it for my case it seemed to do it's job.

Could I replace all variables with vars like you did above?

Comment: Sorry. After a second look I realized that your example uses ´mtcars` and also that you pass the column makes as strings. In that case `{{` is not the right way to go. See my edit which is now adapted to your example.

Comment: Thanks, works brilliantly and it's a less verbose solution than I had in mind. I must admit though that I don't fully understand how the solution works. How exactly does 

.data[]

achieve what I want?